# Odd behaviour boolean in-place operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, boolean-operations

I have a boolean array and I want to do a simple one-element binary dilation, that is, set to `True` all elements inmediately adjacent to other `True` elements.

```
arr=np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0], dtype=bool)
# array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
# set elements before True to also True
arr[:-1] |= arr[1:]; arr
array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This worked just fine. The problem is when I want to set elements after `True` to also `True`

```
arr[1:] |= arr[:-1]; arr
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This result is wrong. Interestingly, when not done in-place, the last operation works just fine:

```
arr[1:] = arr[1:] | arr[:-1]; arr
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I could not find out if boolean operators like `&` or `|` support in-place assigment. If they do, why is `arr[1:] |= arr[:-1]` yielding the wrong result?

Comment: Actually, the "wrong" method worked correctly for me.  What is your numpy version?

Comment: @wim np.__version__: 1.12.1

Comment: @wim for such simple operations scipy  binary dilation can be 30-100x slower

Comment: Works in 1.13.3 for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of such a slice assignment was undefined/buggy in `numpy<1.13.0`.  See the mention in the release notes [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs).

> Operations where ufunc input and output operands have memory overlap produced undefined results in previous NumPy versions, due to data dependency issues. In NumPy 1.13.0, results from such operations are now defined to be the same as for equivalent operations where there is no memory overlap.

Upgrade your numpy version for the "correct" result.

Note that binary dilation is implemented directly in scipy:

```
>>> arr
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation
>>> binary_dilation(arr)
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: i don't think so because i get the 'correct' result with numpy version '1.13.1'

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Thanks for the notice. Actually I bisected it and found the change to be between 1.12.x and 1.13.0. Looks like it was a bugfix, and not about array flags at all.